# Disable context menu item in chrome extension for specific links?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which adds a context menu items for links. I want to enable that item only for specific links (i.e. matching a regex), how can that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: targetUrlPatterns ? of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create

Comment: Yep, I tried it but it didn't work at first due to stupid mistake - second try worked. Thanks! This can be closed.